# Loading navigation menu in every pages

Tags: html, css, browser-cache, nav

I have been googling this for a while and can't find any solution... I am wondering if it is possible to keep a navigation menu in the browser cache eventhough there is an active element that changes from on page to the other (highlighted menu item when on it's page). I m pretty sure browser cache menus to avoid the user to always download the same menu but it doesn4t seem to work on the website I am working on : http://2degreesproject.com.au/Connection

Thanks for you help !

Comment: What is the problem? Your navigation menu is loading on every page.

Comment: Are you trying to make it where you only load new content but keep the menu in place so it doesn't have to reload every time? Like using a frame?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider loading all your other content with ajax. That way you never have to reload the menu. Otherwise, you'll need to pass a bit of information from one page to the next using your server side language or an ajax post. You could always set a cookie and change the value of it on each page to keep track of what the last page was. That's probably the standard way of doing this. Look into how to set cookies, and how to change their values (usually you just unset and reset with a different value, I believe).